# Скрытие в url всей части пути кроме содержимого GET-параметра

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

есть скрипт с GET-параметром, который сейчас открывается по такому пути:

> site.ru/dictionary/word.php?internalid=short

Можете подсказать, возможно ли убрать из урл часть "word.php?internalid="? То есть чтобы та же самая страница открывалась по адресу

> site.ru/dictionary/short

Сейчас мой файл .htaccess выглядит так:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
# Все что выше — рабочий код для других частей сайта. Ниже — моя попытка решить задачу самостоятельно (неудачная)
RewriteRule ^word.php$ word.php?internalid={QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

Comment: RewriteRule ^dictionary/([^/]+)(/|$) /dictionary/word.php?internalid=$1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не установлен `RewriteBase`, то все просто:

```
RewriteRule ^dictionary/short$ dictionary/word.php?internalid=short [NC,QSA,L]
```

В общем случае:

```
RewriteRule ^dictionary/(.*)$ dictionary/word.php?internalid=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, все работает! А можете подсказать, как сделать эту конструкцию универсальной? То есть, чтобы там работало и short и long и square и что угодно в принципе?

Comment: Выше у @splash58 в коментарии есть такой вариант. В момем случае - вся последующая строка уйдет в `?internalid=...`.